# Poincare-Bendixson theorem contradiction help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Lets suppose p is asymptotically stable but not a singularity for the planar differential equation dx/dt=f(x), then for points x sufficiently closed to p we must have x(t) tends to p. so the limit set for any such x is the point p. So the limit set o(x) does not converge to a singularity and does not do a periodic orbit.But this contradicts the Poincare-Bendixson theorem.
What am i saying wrong here?
thank you,

Answer (score 2):

An asymptotically stable point is necessarily a fixed point.

Indeed, suppose that $x(t)$ converges to $p$ as $t \to + \infty$. Then for all $n \geq 1$, there exists $t_n \in (n,n+1)$ such that $x(n+1)-x(n)= x'(t_n)$. Therefore, $$f(p)= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} f(x(t_n))= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} x'(t_n)= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} x(n+1)-x(n)= p-p=0.$$

Comment: thank you for your response, so if I understand well it must be that every asymptotically stable point in a planar differential equation is a singularity

Comment: Exactly, if by a singularity you mean a point $p$ satisfying $f(p)=0$.